# Closed sets in a cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading a set theory text book and I've come upon the section on topologies. (An Introduction to Set Theory and Topology by Ronald Freiwald, p. 105). The author defines the cofinite topology in the usual way:

*T* = {*O* ⊆ *X* : *O* = *∅* or *X* - *O* is finite}

Then he writes:

"In (*X*,*T*), a set *F* is closed iff *F* = ∅ or *F* is finite."

This seems wrong to me. What if X is infinite? Then it is closed but not finite. Am I missing something? If this *is* wrong, what do you think he was trying to get at?

Comment: Did he mean $F$ is closed iff $F=\color{blue}X$ or $F$ is finite?

Comment: That's definitely an error in the text. It should read $F = X$ or $F$ is finite. From the spirit of the introduction to the book, I am sure the author would appreciate it if you let him know about the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you found a typographical error.

I think the author meant that, in the cofinite topology, a set $F$ is closed iff $F=\color{red}X$ or $F$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
F\text{ is closed}&\iff X-F\in T\\
&\iff X-F=\emptyset\text{ or }X-(X-F)\text{ is finite}\\
&\iff F=X\text{ or }F\text{ is finite}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Did you mean $F=X$ or $\color{red}F$ is finite?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes but with the blue color.

Comment: You could align it better using display math and `align`...